# Differential of a function in index notation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It is given that $\lambda = A_{ij} x_i x_j$ where $A_{ij}$ is a constant. The goal is to show that $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x_i} = (A_{ij}+A_{ji})x_j$

My working so far:

$\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i}=A_{ij}x_j+A_{ij}x_i\delta_{ji}=2A_{ij}x_j$

Comment: I do assume that on the right hand side you are using the Einstein summation convention. If that's true, then you should not differentiate with respect to a variable the index of which is also used in the summation. Consider $\frac{\partial A_ {ij}x^i x ^j}{\partial x^k}$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tacit summation you have to account for:
$$\lambda=A_{ij}x_ix_j\equiv \sum_{ij}A_{ij}x_ix_j.$$
This is the so called Einstein Summation convention.

Now, using that $\partial_{x_k}x_i=\delta_{ki}$ and the product rule
\begin{align*}\partial_{x_k}\lambda&=\partial_{x_k}(\sum_{ij}A_{ij}x_ix_j)\\ & =\sum_{ij}A_{ij}(\partial_{x_k}x_i \cdot x_j+ x_i \cdot \partial_{x_k}x_j)\\&=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}\partial_{x_k}x_i \cdot x_j+ \sum_{ij}A_{ij}x_i \cdot \partial_{x_k}x_j\\ &= \sum_{ij}A_{ij}\delta_{ki} \cdot x_j+ \sum_{ij}A_{ij}x_i \cdot \delta_{kj}\\ &=\sum_{j}A_{kj} \cdot x_j+ \sum_{i}A_{ik}x_i \\ & =A_{kj}x_j+A_{jk}x_j
\end{align*}
where in the last step I renamend the indices $i\to j$